# Is starting express like this "const app = require('express')()" considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So title says it all. Never seen anyone use this syntax.

`const app = require('express')()`

I like to keep the main js file lean and have everything in modules so all I have there is 15 lines including comments.

Google didn't help and haven't found an answer here.

Is it bad practice to invoke express as you require it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, **your code should be the simplest and clearest way of reliably meeting your requirements**.  Any code that follows those simple guidelines will not be considered a bad practice in pretty much anyone's book.

There may be other influences on the desired coding style such as team style guidelines, coding style already present in the file/module/project and certain things you may want to do for testing, debugging or reuse.  But, since you don't mention any of those influences, I will assume they are not present here.

So, with that first paragraph in mind, as long as you don't need access to the `express` module elsewhere in this module, then doing:

```
const app = require('express')();
```

is indeed the simplest and clearest way of accomplishing your goal and should not be considered a bad practice - **in fact it should be considered a good practice**.

---

On the other hand, if you were doing this:

```
const app = require('express')();

....


const mainRouter = require('express').Router();


....

const subRouter = require('express').Router();


....

app.use(require('express').static('public'));
```

Then, you'd have simpler and less redundant code (and perhaps a little faster since there are fewer function calls) if you loaded the express module into its own variable which you could then use everywhere else in that module:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

....


const mainRouter = express.Router();


....

const subRouter = express.Router();


....

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it pretty much sums up my issues in an easy to read format. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider is that the `express` module exposes some other functionality that you might want to make use of later (e.g. `express.static`). In your case you would have to `require` express again to gain access to it:

```
app.use(require('express').static());
```

Other than that there is no reason it's "bad practise". It just depends on what you intend to leverage from the module.

Comment: Luckily, the module is most likely cached

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh Yes, Node caches the modules once they're required. But the code will become unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Can't know if I was downvoted for answering a question someone thought not worth answering, or if there's a legitimate problem with what I've written. I'd genuinely like to know if it's the latter being in the intermediate bracket for NodeJS development.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. As to your suggestion: This is not an issue since I have these settings as a module as well and I set my view engine and static files there, thus I'm requiring express inside that module. I guess it's all about convention?

Comment: Agree.  Downvoters should post why they downvote so a downvote is an opportunity to learn what needs improving in the answer rather than just "drive-by dissent" with no chance for the community to benefit from the feedback and just a confused author.

Comment: @zakachen It's basically up to you and any teams you work in. With this sort of thing the "right" way is whatever the other members of your team or contributors to the project are used to and comfortable with. It's totally a matter of opinion (which is why I was likely downvoted for answering the question).

Answer (score 1):

This is **not a bad practise** rather this is a **short version** of following code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, to create an identifier for ***reuse*** and ***better communication to readers***.

---

*More thought just about `require()`*

Since `require()` takes the responsibility to load and cache modules, some argues that it should be placed before app initialization. I see many example codes follows this style. However I think it really depends on how the package/code quality is ensured in the specific project.